# Center screen at a SVG object

Tags: svg, dictionary, gps, center, pan

I'm developing a gps tracking app for android using custom SVG maps. I can print my exact position at the SVG map through the device's GPS but I'm having some difficulties when I want to pan/center the screen at my position. Basically the idea is to keep moving/panning the map automatically while i'm moving so the user won't have to do it by himself. I'm using the jquery.panzoom (https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom). Has anyone did this before, would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Why not just amend the viewBox as you get an update ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using SVG fragment identifiers.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#SVGFragmentIdentifiers

Basically you can supply a viewBox in the URL of the SVG you are linking to.  That's assuming you are using an external SVG file (ie not embedded).

So for instance, if you want to show the top left 200x200 of an SVG, you can do:

http://url.of.my.svg/map.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,0,200,200))

An example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/New_Zealand_location_map.svg#svgView(viewBox(800,1600,400,400))

Then when the GPS position changes, you just update the URL.  It saves having to mess about with the contents of the file.

The only proviso is that I haven't checked that the Android WebView supports it.  I'm assuming you are using a WebView??

Comment: It's been a long time, but i wanted to thank you anyway. And yes, i was using kind of a webview... Cordova Framework.